# Trying to implement plug-in-palettemap of gimp for command line for batch processing

Tags: command-line, gimp

I am trying to implement plug-in-palettemap (This plug-in maps the contents of the specified drawable with the active palette.) in gimp for use in command line. Gimp GUI Menu Option: Colors-> Map-> Palette Map.
But its throwing error. How do I select the active palette for processing the image?

```
(define (batch-color-palette pattern)
(let* ((filelist (cadr (file-glob pattern 1))))
  (while (not (null? filelist))
     (let* ((filename (car filelist))
            (image (car (gimp-file-load RUN-NONINTERACTIVE
                                        filename filename)))
            (drawable (car (gimp-image-get-active-layer image))))

       (plug-in-palettemap RUN-NONINTERACTIVE 
               image drawable)
       (gimp-file-save RUN-NONINTERACTIVE
                       image drawable filename filename)
       (gimp-image-delete image))
     (set! filelist (cdr filelist)))))
```

I am getting the error:

```
GIMP-Error: Calling error for procedure 'gimp-palette-entry-get-color':
Palette 'Standard' not found
```

I tried reading the active palette. But it did not work. Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was I was using gimp command with -d option. Need to remove that so that the palette and data are also included in processing.

```
gimp -i -b batch-color-palette.....
```

details on gimp [batch mode page](https://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Basic_Batch/)